# undefined method `attachments' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building one application using paperclip to upload multiple files. The files are being saved in the backend. I checked it with the console.
While displaying the files in show page it is giving me

```
undefined method `attachments' for nil:NilClass
```

show.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
      <ul class="thumbnails files">
        <% @gallery.attachments.each do |attachment| %>
          <li class="span3" id="attachment_<%= attachment.id %>">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <%= image_tag attachment.image_url %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

controller.rb

```
def create
@gallery = current_user.gallery.new(galley_params)
respond_to do |format|
  if @gallery.save
    if params[:attachments]
      params[:attachments].each {|attachment|
        @gallery.attachments.create(attachment:  attachment)
      }
    end
  end
  format.js{ render nohing: true}
end
end
```

Can someone help what is this error mean in my code.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is quite descriptive. `@gallery` is `nil`, so you probably don't set `@gallery` variable in `show` action (code of `create` action is irrelevant here). So you should have something like this:

```
def show
  @gallery = current_user.gallery
end
```